# Syntax Rendered in Visualforce not working

Tags: visualforce, rendered

I already tried several ways to try this rendered in my code, but the header still show up, and the value is already like the criteria.how to make the header is show/not showing based on the criteria. this is my code:

```
   <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!arrRateMap[Key]}" var="r" id="ratecardtable">
        <apex:column title="{!r.Notes}">
            <apex:inputCheckbox id="productFlag" value="{!r.isSelected}" rendered="{!r.isDisabled = false}" onchange="updateRatecardFlag({!famCol})"></apex:inputCheckbox>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column value="{!r.P.Name}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!r.R.Brand__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!r.R.Description__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!r.P.Family}"/>
        <apex:column rendered="{!CONTAINS(r.P.Family, 'FX')}">
            <apex:facet name="header">
                <apex:outputText value="Xendit Rate BPS"/>
            </apex:facet>
            <apex:outputText value="{!r.R.Xendit_Rate_BPS__c}"/>
        </apex:column>
        
        <apex:column rendered="{!NOT(CONTAINS(r.P.Family, 'FX'))}">
            <apex:facet name="header">Rate Per Txn</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputText value="{!r.R.Rate_Per_Txn__c}"/>
        </apex:column>
        
        <apex:column rendered="{!NOT(CONTAINS(r.P.Family, 'FX'))}">
            <apex:facet name="header">Rate Per TPV</apex:facet>
            <apex:outputText value="{!r.R.Rate_Per_TPV__c}"/>
        </apex:column>
                        
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

[image]

the Xendit BPS should not showing up.

Comment: There is an open issue with Contains found [here][1], Looking at the open bug if suggests using FIND over contains that is found [here][2]

Going into this more, ideally you need to show the logs and make sure the properties are set correctly and visible to the UI. Also highly recommend just re-building this in LWC


  [1]: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4397/unexpected-behavior-with-isblank-and-contains-functions-in-visualforce-page?rq=1
  [2]: https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000qQ83RAAS/discrepencies-with-isblank-and-contains-functions-in-visualforce-page

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue with Contains found [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4397/unexpected-behavior-with-isblank-and-contains-functions-in-visualforce-page?rq=1), Looking at the open bug if suggests using FIND over contains that is found [here](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000qQ83RAAS/discrepencies-with-isblank-and-contains-functions-in-visualforce-page)

Going into this more, ideally you need to show the logs and make sure the properties are set correctly and visible to the UI. Also highly recommend just re-building this in LWC